# Is it possibly to automatically indent HTML source outputted by PHP?

Tags: php, html, indentation, auto-indent, view-source

As a perfectionist, I like having valid & correctly indented HTML outputted by PHP.

I have a few complex webapps with IT-minded users, and they like to be able to View source and not see a garbled mess.

Currently I use this function I wrote:

```
function nl($tabs = 0)
{
    return "\r\n" . str_repeat("\t", $tabs);
}
```

Using it like so to add a newline and the required number of tabs:

```
if(array_key_exists('field', $row)){
    echo '<td>' . $row['field'] . '</td>' . nl(4);
}
```

Is there anything built-in to PHP, or is there a class I can use to do this indentation automatically?

Comment: In the past having readable HTML was the job of the writer, now this is done automagically by the browsers using tools like Firebug or Chrome's developer tools. You should focus on making your PHP readable instead of the output (the HTML).

Comment: @panther Trollololol, because Linux is still king of the web (and sans-license fee). I use .NET where requested/required, but it's typically open-source that is wanted.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: Doesn't your browser have a prettify-button for source code? that saves the trouble of writing all those pointless (and in your case flawed) indentation functions. By flawed I mean, for example how `return "\r\n"` should be `return PHP_EOL`

Comment: I wouldn't do that, but you could collect your html in a variable (or by output_buffering) and parse it before echoing.

Comment: Maybe you can write functions like 'openTag', 'closeTag' and `writeContent`. The first two can increment and decrement an indentation counter. But doing so means having a lot of extra function calls, possibly resulting in a slightly slower page. Also, not all HTML tags (unlike XML) need closing, so that might mess up your indentation.

Comment: There was something about auto indenting a while ago with javaScript, and CSS.

Comment: @DannyBeckett they were trying to do stuff with the pixels indented from like how the old fashioned newspapers would do L/C/R aligning of story titles.

Comment: @IGotRoot Likely not for View Source. I'd be interested if you could find a link?

Comment: @IGotRoot As I expected, not for View Source.

Answer (score 8):

When using output buffers you can use DOMDocument and set formatOutput to true before flushing the buffers to the client / browser.

ie:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors( TRUE );

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->validateOnParse = FALSE;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = TRUE;
$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
$om->loadHTML( mb_convert_encoding( ob_get_contents(), 'UTF-8' ) );

libxml_clear_errors();

/*
 perform any other operations on dom elements you wish
*/

$buffer = $dom->saveHTML();
ob_end_clean();
echo trim( $buffer );/* send data to client/browser */
```

Comment: Good answer. Bad idea.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen This particular web app is heavily data driven, and being able to view the source (readable) is sometimes very useful.

Comment: @DannyBeckett Formatting output only serves to slow down the website. It is none of my business, but you could at least make it optional. Using a GET variable as a "switch", like `?format_output=true`, could be an idea.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen That's a good idea. The IT staff have a particular session var set anyway, distinct to other work units staff.

Comment: @RamRaider use the KISS principle, and take it on the client side with a single line of code.

Comment: @IGotRoot I don't want a client-side solution.